# I keep getting an error in PyCharm, No tests were found and Empty Suite

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting an error while trying to do a test in PyCharm. It keeps saying No tests were found and empty suite. I've tried to tinker with a bunch of different things and can't seem to get this figured out. Does anyone know what the issue is?

```
import unittest
from city_functions import city_country


class TestCitiesCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """Tests the combined function in city_functions"""

    def test_city_country(self):
        """Does seattle united states of america work"""
        seattle = city_country('seattle', 'united states of america')
        self.assertEqual(seattle, 'seattle, united states of america')

    def test_city_country_population(self):
        """Does seattle united states of america population 500000 work?"""
        seattle = city_country('seattle', 'united states of america', 500000)
        self.assertEqual(seattle, 'seattle, united states of america, population 500000')


unittest.main()
```

city_functions.py -

```
def city_country(city, country, population=''):
    if population:
        city = city.title() + ', ' + country.title() + ', population ' + str(population)
    else:
        city = city.title() + ', ' + country.title()
    return city
```

Comment: Try ```if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()```

Comment: How are you running your tests? Also @EricTruett, the only purpose of a name guard would be to _prevent_ the tests from being run when the module is imported. It doesn't seem like it would be at all relevant when unittest isn't discovering tests.

Comment: @Brian I am just clicking run within PyCharm.

Comment: @Tr3s3 There is a fairly significant amount of configuration offered in PyCharm's run profiles for the unittest module. Please include this in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Experienced same, but if you take out `unittest.main()`, your test should work fine.

or have

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

[This][1] explains why and when to use if __name__ =='__main__'


  [1]: https://sparkbyexamples.com/python/python-if-__name__-__main__-explain/#:~:text=By%20using%20the%20if%20__,a%20module%20by%20another%20script.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I just did, thanks